# problemas con password_verify()

Tags: php, crud

Sé que hay un montón de hilos abiertos con esta duda pero por más que pruebo los ejemplos, no me funciona nada y ya me estoy volviendo loco. Tengo el siguiente código con el que trato de iniciar sesión recogiendo el id del login y el password y llamo a mi función del DAO para comprobarlo:

```
    $empDao = new EmpleadoDAO();

if(isset($_POST['idEmpleado']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $idLogin = $_POST['idEmpleado'];
    $passLogin = $_POST['password'];

    if($empDao->compruebaEmpleado($idLogin, $passLogin)){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['idEmpleado'] = $idLogin;
        header("Location:../index.php");
    }else{
        $errorLogin = "id o contraseña incorrectos";
    }
}
```

Mi función DAO es la siguiente:

```
public function compruebaEmpleado($idEmpleado, $password)
    {
        $consulta=$this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM empleado WHERE idEmpleado=:idEmpleado");
        $consulta->bindValue('idEmpleado',$idEmpleado);
        $consulta->execute();
        $empleado = $consulta->fetch();
        $empleadoRecuperado= new Empleado();
        if (password_verify($password, $empleado['password'])){
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Y por si acaso, los empleados los guardo así:

```
public function insertarEmpleado($empleado)
    {

        $password = password_hash($empleado->getPassword(), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO empleado (idEmpleado, password, nombre, apellidos, email, departamento, costeHora, foto) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $empleado->getIdEmpleado());
        $stmt->bindValue(2, $password);
        $stmt->bindValue(3, $empleado->getNombre());
        $stmt->bindValue(4, $empleado->getApellidos());
        $stmt->bindValue(5, $empleado->getEmail());
        $stmt->bindValue(6, $empleado->getDepartamento());
        $stmt->bindValue(7, $empleado->getCosteHora());
        $stmt->bindValue(8, $empleado->getFoto());
        $resultadoRegistro = $stmt->execute();
        if ($resultadoRegistro) {
            return $this->db->lastInsertId();
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Los insert me los hace correctamente. Me guarda las contraseñas hasheadas, pero a la hora de comprobarlas, me salta el mensaje de "login o contraseña incorrectos"...

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Ayuda por favor!!

Comment: Creo que no haces el mismo proceso de convertirla en hash a luego comprobarla en texto. La mejor opción es que metas `echos` en los resultados o ir paso a paso con algún phpStorm o IDE preferido.

Comment: He modificado la función del DAO. También he localizado el problema. Está justo en la función password_verify()... Si hago un echo del password que recibo del argumento, me imprime lo que escribo en el campo password del login. Si hago otro echo de del passsword que tengo en la base de datos, me imprime la contraseña con los hash correspondientes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo seteas al objeto, tendrás que usar un getter, pero para usarlo inmediatamente lo haría así:

```
password_verify($password, $empleado['password'])
```

En tu código le estás pasando lo que devuelva el setter

Comment: Efectivamente!!!! Muchísimas gracias!!! Editaré mi respuesta para que todo quede correcto.